# does it matter if i have coded my program with buttons in wrong order?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

i am using visual studio 2013 C# Windows Form application with multiple Tabcontrol tabs, which each have multiple buttons. I have written the code for the buttons that I know the values for.

After doing this, I realized that the buttons aren't coded in the order they appear in form1.cs, as I have done some here and there on different tabs.

For example: On form1.cs I have button2 on tab1 coded then next down is button79 on tab5.

Does it matter which order they are coded on the form1.cs?  The program works fine, but should I change the order of coded buttons?

Will it make my program faster if the buttons on form1.cs are all coded in order from button 1 down the page to button100?

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question. As is is very difficult to read and to answer you.

Comment: Dear god, how do you expect us to read that?

Comment: (No, it doesn't really matter.)

Comment: That is very poorly organised. In essence I think you're asking if the names of your buttons needs to be sequential depending on where they are. No, they don't

Comment: ok sorry about the question format i suck at asking questions lol anyway i take RAWLING's answer of "No, it doesnt really matter" thanks for such a quick response all of you

Answer (score 4):

The names of the buttons you are referring to are the names of the buttons you can use in your C# code. The designer has the option to rename this standaard `button1` to a more sensible name.

But since it is pure the name used in code, it doesnt matter much.

But when working in the C# code it is not very handy to work with `button1`. So if you name this for example `orderButton` then the `orderButton.Click += ...` makes much more sense in C#.

---

**TL;DR:**

No it doesn't matter, because your program users wont see your code.

Comment: Yes, I'd definitely like to re-iterate that if there are 70+ buttons, they *really* need to have easily identifiable names!

Answer (score 0):

> im wondering if it matters which order they are coded on the form1.cs

No.  It doesn't matter which order your buttons are in your code in relation to how they're displayed.  The logic (in this case, code-behind) of your application is [loosely coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) to your display, which is a good thing.